# Helm Secrets Unable To Recognize Data

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to implement Helm Secrets on a simple application.
I want to install the app using the Helm Secrets plugin. Here's my encrypted templates/secrets.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: ENC[AES256_GCM,data:Hcs=,iv:U+0hlPz+L5HP0SqWmzJgxNftRYNc3BTHeYetefrDxQo=,tag:AXwtAjcHv8VsL1PC8XjOmA==,type:str]
kind: ENC[AES256_GCM,data:YLEC3Zg/,iv:L3CL9DzUEHEKlucZcY+Su+OYKC+1VCTvVEFcc0iX7RI=,tag:sS7rauZq1nYpAA/gesA66Q==,type:str]
metadata:
    name: ENC[AES256_GCM,data:KQvvSmDMSw==,iv:LvXweR3aTgVTc9IAa3f6uJHbpHGf2jYHtGWq629Yqdo=,tag:AXIrhiEjhAXlDNmFyYKyPg==,type:str]
    labels:
        app: ENC[AES256_GCM,data:2GbBtSKC4Y7sYxw=,iv:zGmUTLcYwjUvZ0VAmw92e63na/+lsOlP16RD9LjcKjE=,tag:fR5QPK6587K1peod5nf4BA==,type:str]
type: ENC[AES256_GCM,data:B2WQyYNe,iv:S0q8nzu5pDGAem5KuB4aRRq9tOtpThOgshxn8iwGmq8=,tag:pV2JsX14j6433XBLpwdUhQ==,type:str]
data:
    password: ENC[AES256_GCM,data:p6/fadwzX+vx10yc,iv:OIckX7T72t+5lHvAX2r8ybFPQ8Yrc4po4G3Y/BJyT3s=,tag:fuGxBTl3XLInvXew4quc6g==,type:str]
sops:
    kms: []
    gcp_kms: []
    azure_kv: []
    lastmodified: '2019-09-02T10:13:37Z'
    mac: ENC[AES256_GCM,data:zlqeKsbTdyBUoXnbhyXOAeCuIrdzO9AL2ydwUGFNd5ZFG+BbibstqosxZ1vnGZip58JQaK7e3ewibWj/CD7Ev2crTEk2jpEfbqYSp17s3hYpefNUe2esGKfb6/E0FgcdC2onxHKwv1CnHEGh5DwQdBT6JIfTvialEG1DKmYVcLY=,iv:aoqvOl0xUP6JBvtmOEDwD5Ejq3AmgJ/tUouPPf7AJZU=,tag:IsnFW8Lu/+v7xQth4cW++A==,type:str]
    pgp:
    -   created_at: '2019-09-02T10:13:37Z'
        enc: |
            -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

            hQIMA+GCaQB9sLS8AQ//dYLstPngZwDPenAGvb7xasCQSa7g5Qv81I3vg0kI1YoM
            Ydhpf9QrG3YKIZMlMTmu1X6wiFVZI74Ig0telatqYl2RoUKWtDKfyHPlUgSVd+yx
            lcouwrzU745alGSPIIgWFwoSnprzTNGXjWlafBIq++uCjlr7MQ/SvgZ0oOTOQvOh
            vq0f+BXbJ2MIX4rCeuL6TsJA71sohLnfbBS7Y3/Ci7Wo0//TnqTvOt0/OWPcvBF4
            4+WmUT6mSfsakYht5inSWWatvaXNCf7j/i/YAjzy9Jyzs/9OyozFrnvnqtbVDeQ6
            mnppoW0iCT9z6P6AzzivB3xkk/dMC66ym2VhwtHs73xqpg4DDesGVdC1aQCgUleG
            PQ8WHW4JduoS9rF81Pmb0IEy/VGjB5WlUYgl0yygc/hki7coBlN5d/k3o2DcO3L3
            g0tdEFML0Uhmt3VbW/b63D4+NIt8Sc64JkZs/0du/a5v4kI8RaNhh6LF1678K9+9
            Sxa2x4YcyTNQcxVnJBTyMrthTKk5F+X2rPUwglhjaC9Ag5OizbjQMYRhCX+Sa8to
            RWYGbiVcOmdBwd/eUXjTCm1vXMrrV5oq1C0jsBz5SOj1HoIM17WHcyEFveUG2tj1
            nSqCRYQaJj2g1yj6yKpm9wNH6aNTaHqmWm6lBzHP2LLzWNmFE7FuDtlVXx/urczS
            WAG88jN9VRblOlMfqjmwgkbqG9Zp0oV6AgtqOYe/91xdNPQomJzEEyTvezLQwdAt
            buTSOrbZzy3TN9jX/6GySpGDXwrUOFrM+uDHVmPKt6a/Fr+TPgJDYLw=
            =IqOl
            -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
        fp: 6E7DB0D1CA47AC3C09F70B10410AC2AFD3DA7DE1
    unencrypted_suffix: _unencrypted
    version: 3.3.1
```

Unencrypted, the file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: db-pass
    labels:
        app: mariadbtest
type: Opaque
data:
    password: UGFzc3dkMiE=
```

If I am running `helm secrets install --name=webtest . -f templates/secrets.yaml` with the secrets file unencrypted, it works fine, but when I try to run it with the file encrypted it gives me this error:

```
Error: validation failed: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "ENC[AES256_GCM,data:Y8GlCcMF,iv:y+v+BrbvoTd9Yx3sVwYTyJ2SCgHW5uh+Ph7aOXsIoR8=,tag:pe7S1fepnKXqvJaVRdcvKQ==,type:str]" in version "ENC[AES256_GCM,data:/Eg=,iv:KqccclIvL3+uhcgGACum5kJQ4pzHNTRjqBRQ4Zs3rCM=,tag:Rk9YL7kz3sAsa7WhNdaOeA==,type:str]"
```

Any solution to this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @A_Suh No, i did not

Comment: same issue was raised on the github https://github.com/futuresimple/helm-secrets/issues/116 Try to move your `secrets.yaml` somewhere  to another directory outside of the helm chart and run `helm secrets install . -f <path-to-file>/secrets.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your [helm-secrets](https://github.com/futuresimple/helm-secrets) plugin doesn't work properly and for some reason doesn't decrypt values which are present in encrypted version of your `templates/secrets.yaml` file before passing them to `helm install` and it is unable to recognize those still encrypted values as something which makes sense to it and error message itself seems quite obvious.

I assume you created your encrypted file version by using `helm secrets enc templates/secrets.yaml` on the same system using same gpg key, correct ?

Did you install it by using `helm plugin install https://github.com/futuresimple/helm-secrets` ?

Does `helm secrets view templates/secrets.yaml` return you unencrypted version of your file properly ? Please make sure you didn't miss any of the steps described in [this](https://developer.epages.com/blog/tech-stories/kubernetes-deployments-with-helm-secrets/) article.

Comment: Yes, when I use `helm secrets view templates/secrets.yaml` it does show the unencrypted version of the file